# The item could not be indexed successfully because the item failed in the indexing subsystem

Tags: search, crawling

I'm trying to find an explanation of the crawl error "The item could not be indexed successfully because the item failed in the indexing subsystem.". I get a lot of these when indexing a file share. Does anyone know where i can find info around this error?

Comment: Did you try to delete the index and run a full crawl afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue is related to space on the disk holding the index. We started with a small disk with only around 5GB and apparently these errors started to show up when there was around 1GB left on that disk. We resized the disk for the index and after that we were able to index all items on the fileshare without these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this error for over a week trying everything I could find out on the internet and no luck.

I did expand disk space and reset the index and it still did not work, so I rebooted the crawl server, reset the index and everything worked fine. I hope this helps.